# Putting grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layouts, grids-graticules

I create a layout in QGIS, I'm going to put a grid (LAT and LONG); so the problem is my map scale is too small so the interval must be less than 1 degree.

Comment: Do you want it using python (pyqgis) or using the QGIS  map composer interface?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What were the precise steps that you performed when you tried to do this?